# what are artifactory nuget snapshots? and snapshots in general

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, artifactory

Tried google artifactory snapshots and everything that comes up is for maven. I use nuget. I have a "Max Unique Snaphosts" setting for my nuget repos- what is this?

I thought snapshots were a generic artifactory feature for all types of repos but looks like its platform specific? Like I said i only see docs for maven snapshots.

I have artifactory cloud

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your questions, please let me elaborate more. 
"Snapshot versions" are considered "staging" versions that you are using and testing before releasing "Release versions" to your users/customers. Snapshots and Release versions can be often be related to Maven (since this is the terminology in Maven), however, this can be related to any package type.

With regards to your enquiry about "Max Unique Snapshots", I recommend you to read JFrog's wiki page about ["Managing Disk Space Usage"](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Disk+Space+Usage#ManagingDiskSpaceUsage-LimitingtheNumberofSnapshots).

I hope this clarifies further.

Comment: But nuget doesn't support Maven style snapshots. So what are snapshots in jfrog for nuget work like?

Comment: You are correct, it's not the traditional "Maven Snapshots" however, there are users that would like to work in a "snapshot-like" environment until releasing it. In order to the snapshot cleanup to work in JFrog Artifactory, all you need to do is to verify that you are deploying your artifacts by the layout you set to the repository or to edit your layout to fit your deployment path.